Running React Fastapi app in a google cloud instance using docker-compose & nginx

I've tried to open my react app through docker-compose.
Here's my files:
Frontend dockerfile:
FROM node:20 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Backend dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

Docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

And then I start docker-compose up --build -d
Everything's complete OK, writes that project successfully built, but if I try my server URL in a browser - nothing. Cannot access the site Site xx.xxx.xxx.xx does not allow a connection to be established. What am I doing wrong? Thanx in advance!
